# How to capture reply rabbitmq message Corresponding to a RPC.call Request message in OpenStack?

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc, openstack

RPC call and cast are two different types of message passing protocol in OpenStack. In case of  RPC.call, the invoker (or caller) waits for the reply or ack messsage  from the worker (callee).

I am trying to intercept all RPC messages (both Request & Reply Message) passing through rabbitmq system in OpenStack. In OpenStack all request messages pass through a single exchange named "nova". Attaching a new queue to the "nova" exchange, I can capture request Message.

Now, I want to capture reply messages that are sent back to callee. Reply messages can be captured by "direct Consumer" as specified by   [AMQP and Nova](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/devref/rpc.html) and excerpt as follows

```
a Direct Consumer comes to life if (an only if) a rpc.call operation is executed; this object is    
instantiated and used to receive a response message from the queuing system; Every consumer connects to  
a unique direct-based exchange via a unique exclusive queue; its life-cycle is limited to the message 
delivery; the exchange and queue identifiers are determined by a *UUID generator*, and are marshaled in 
the message sent by the Topic Publisher (only rpc.call operations).
```

In order to capture reply message, I have tried to connect to a  direct exchange with corresponding msg_id or request_id. I am not sure what would be correct exchange id for capturing reply of a specific rpc.call.

Any idea what would be the exchange id what I may use to capture reply from a rpc.call message ? What is the *UUID generator* as specified in the excerpt I attached ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of the OpenStack implementation, but when doing RPC over Messaging Systems, usually messages carry a `correlation_id` identifier that should be used to track requests.

See: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html